# Web app deployment

Tags: web-deployment, web-deployment-project

We have developed a web app in vs 2010, using c#, .net framework 4.0.  We should support various OS, and IIS versions.

For earlier versions of our app, we used the deployment project in visual studio, which creates a .msi and a setup.exe
We prefer to not make the customers download multiple files, so we've been giving out just the .msi
 - we also have found that (in win2008) the msi needs to be run with admin priviledges, and it is difficult to do for an msi.

We'd like to avoid any install that needs to use the command line.
Hopefully we don't need to make the customers download additional prerequisites.

How are people deploying their web apps?
Thanks in advance

Comment: "We should support various OS, and IIS versions."  uhhh...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your project is a web application project you can provide a Web Deployment Package and that can be installed using IIS Manager.  For a description of the process see this overview:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd394698.aspx

For details on how to create and install a package, see this:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465323.aspx

And for more resources, the MSDN deployment content map:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386521.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to push instead of pull, please consider looking to [TeamCity](http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/)

This BLOG entry should help: http://www.troyhunt.com/2010/11/you-deploying-it-wrong-teamcity.html

And I'm pretty sure that most people deploy their web apps :)